# In Node.js how do I communicate with client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example suppose client side I have a JavaScript function

```
function getLocation() {
    var latitude = ...;
    var longitude = ...;
}
```

The coordinates are retrieved using a function call to Google or similar.  How can I transmit this information to my Node.js server?

Comment: Why not use some kind of templating system? It'll make your life easier

Comment: @elclanrs how would templating possibly help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way?  Set up [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and have your client side code communicate via Ajax (for example, using jQuery).

```
(function() {
  var app, express;

  express = require("express");

  app = express.createServer();

  app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    return app.use(app.router);
  });

  app.configure("development", function() {
    return app.use(express.errorHandler({
      dumpExceptions: true,
      showStack: true
    }));
  });

  app.post("/locations", function(request, response) {
    var latitude, longitude;
    latitude = request.body.latitude;
    longitude = request.body.longitude;
    return response.json({}, 200);
  });

  app.listen(80);

}).call(this);
```

On the client side, you might call it like this:

```
var latitude = 0
  , longitude = 0; // Set from form

$.post({
  url: "http://localhost/locations",
  data: {latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude},
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("Success");
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Note this code is simply an example; you'll have to work out the error handling, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

By making an HTTP request, just like you would with any other server side program in a web application.

You could do this with the [XMLHttpRequest object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), or by generating a `<form>` and then submitting it, or a variety of other methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you need (soft) real-time capabilities, I recommend using the [Socket.io library](http://socket.io/). With socket, node can also push data to your client side scripts.

Comment: He most likely does not need socket.io for this

Comment: Haha, why did you mention WebSockets on Quentin's post, then? :D. It's exactly what socket.io provides but with cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [NowJS](http://nowjs.com/) will be a perfect fit for you. Example:

```
// On the Node.JS server

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(httpServer);

everyone.now.getServerInfo = function(callback){
  db.doQuery(callback);
}

// In the browser

<script>

now.getServerInfo(function(data){
  // data contains the query results
});

</script>
```

You can put variables and functions in a common namespace (i.e. the `now` object), from the client to the server and the other way around.

Comment: nowjs is a complex solution if he only needs to get a few small pieces of data

Comment: agreed. But he doesn't say he only needs a few pieces of data; he just gave an example

Comment: Right now, the Nowjs.com server is down and the github code is over 2 years old. Also, doing an `npm install now` failed to build, requiring python to compile.

Comment: I've noticed one problem in the code: JavaScript is meant to be used in a `.js` file. Having it part of the HTML source code is a bad habit and makes it very weak if an XSS attack or similar.  However I understand that this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). The [node modules section also has a section covering RPC](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-rpc). I think you should have a look at [DNode](https://github.com/substack/dnode). Have a look at the [DNode on the browser section](https://github.com/substack/dnode#dnode-on-the-browser).